# How to align background image in Safari?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, safari

I am trying to align my background image in Safari but, whereas in Firefox, Chrome, Explorer, etc, the image is centred with the footer at the bottom, in Safari the footer rides up half the page so half the background image is below the footer, and half above.

You can view this page in Safari desktop. https://adsler.co.uk/events/ to see the issue. Difficult to identify HTML CSS here as a problem only exists in Safari.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [mcve], because once your site is fixed this question will stop being useful to other people who come looking at it, there will be no record of the problem.

Comment: I beg to differ, but I've provided the link to the site and I don't know what css or html would be relevant here, other than the background image itself. Posting code for that would be pointless, please could you let me know exactly where i should look to identify the css /html that is causing Safari to display incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: Looks the same in Chrome and Safari to me. So either you need to post enough HTML and CSS to reproduce the problem and let us know the specific version of Safari you are using, or else you already fixed the problem with an update since posting this question, in which case you can see why Jason Aller made his comment.

Comment: Thank you cjl750. It seems that the issue may predominate in larger screen versions running Safari. I had thought it was smaller screens too but perhaps you're right to point out the discrepancy.